# imap_search search by hyperlink in body

Tags: imap

How to use imap_search, for search by hyperlink in body.

For eg. if body contain html like `...<a href="www.test.com">Test</a>...` And I trying search as

`$emails = imap_search($stream, 'Body "www.test.com"');`

Above search is not returning any result.

Is it possible to search by hyperlink as above?

Comment: Probably because of the training space. Pay attention to the error emssages from the server.

Comment: Keep in mind that the breadth and quality of the search support for IMAP-servers is very software specific, and full-text search is often a weak point.  Many might ignore HTML altogether, only support full-words, or in some cases, not support it at all.